# How to iterate over vector of shared pointers to a Class

Tags: c++, set, smart-pointers

I have a class:

```
class Company {
    public:
    int floors;
    std::set<std::string> managers;
};
```

And another class which has the following:

```
class Another {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Company>> comp;
    }
```

If I have this function which needs to find if any of the managers have the name in any of the Company classes in comp, how I can I iterate over the `comp` vector, especially its managers set for each Company in comp?

```
bool Another::look_for(std::string name);
```

should return true if any of the managers in comp have 'name'

thanks for any help

Comment: Work out how to write a loop that loops over every element of `comp`.   In the body of that loop, where you are working with a single instance of `Company` work out how to check if the set contains the specified string.     You can work out all the parts by examining the documentation for `vector`, `shared_ptr`, and `set`   (and possibly use a standard algorithm to simplify).    I won't give a code sample, as it is not too difficult, and you'll learn more by working out the details for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
bool Another::look_for(std::string name)
{
    for (auto &c : comp) {
        if (c->managers.find(name) != c->managers.end())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

bool Another::look_for(std::string name)
{
    return std::find_if(
        comp.begin(), comp.end(),
        [&](auto &c) { return c->managers.find(name) != c->managers.end(); }
    ) != comp.end();
}
```

Comment: Super answer! If it is possible, I would recommend changing the function argument form ´std::string name´ to ´const std::string &name´ or if you have the sufficient C++ version ´std::stringview name´

Comment: @schorsch312 `std::string_view`

Comment: Thank you! Quick question if I'm looking for a string in managers, how can I return the specific index it is at?

Comment: @user122 which index? The company index? The manager index in a company? In any case, simply use a normal index-based `for` loop instead of a range-based `for` loop.